# Obtener dato de fila anterior - Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bueno tengo una lista de personas que están registrados en una clínica (uno de sus datos es una fecha de Ingreso), y lo que no  me sale es obtener una fecha pasada del paciente. La fecha del paciente si entro a la clínica anteriormente. Solo necesito sacar la FechaIngreso de la fila anterior.

Mi código:

```
WITH PacientesDiagnosticos AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50
        p.IdPaciente      , 
        a.IdAtencion as IdAtencion,
        (p.ApellidoPaterno+' '+p.ApellidoMaterno+' '+p.PrimerNombre) as Nombres,
        --esto de abajo estuve avanzando para sacar las fechas o nose si esta bien :s
        --DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.IdAtencion ORDER BY a.FechaIngreso) AS NumFechaIngreso,
        a.FechaIngreso as FechaIngreso,
        a.FechaEgreso as FechaEgreso,
        d.Descripcion AS Dignostico,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY a.IdAtencion ORDER BY d.Descripcion) AS NumDiagnosticos
    FROM Pacientes p
    JOIN Atenciones a ON p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
    JOIN AtencionesDiagnosticos ad ON a.IdAtencion = ad.IdAtencion
    JOIN Diagnosticos d ON ad.IdDiagnostico = d.IdDiagnostico
)
SELECT IdPaciente      , 
        IdAtencion,
       Nombres, 
       FechaIngreso,
       FechaEgreso,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 1 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 2 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 3 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 4 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico4,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 5 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico5,
       MAX( CASE WHEN NumDiagnosticos = 6 THEN Dignostico END) AS Dignostico6
FROM PacientesDiagnosticos
GROUP BY IdPaciente,
        IdAtencion,
       Nombres,
       FechaIngreso,
       FechaEgreso;
```

Pero bueno, segun buscando en internet. La solucion seria usar las funciones LAG / LEAD para poder obtener un dato de una fila anterior, pero el problema es que eso trabaja a partir de Sql Server 2012, y yo uso el 2008 R2...Hay alguna solucion para el del 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible, una forma sencilla, sería generar una secuencia en la consulta principal, que numere en orden, cada `FechaIngreso` de cada `IdPaciente`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.IdPaciente, ORDER BY FechaIngreso) AS RN
```

Luego, cuando se explota la CTE inicial, podemos usar un `LEFT JOIN` para acceder a la misma consulta solo que una fila hacia atrás:

```
FROM PacientesDiagnosticos T1
    LEFT JOIN PacientesDiagnosticos T2
        ON T2.IdPaciente = T1.IdPaciente
        AND T2.RN = T1.RN - 1
```

Tu Consulta debiera quedar algo así:

```
WITH PacientesDiagnosticos AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50
            p.IdPaciente      , 
            a.IdAtencion as IdAtencion,
            (p.ApellidoPaterno+' '+p.ApellidoMaterno+' '+p.PrimerNombre) as Nombres,
            --esto de abajo estuve avanzando para sacar las fechas o nose si esta bien :s
            --DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.IdAtencion ORDER BY a.FechaIngreso) AS NumFechaIngreso,
            a.FechaIngreso as FechaIngreso,
            a.FechaEgreso as FechaEgreso,
            d.Descripcion AS Dignostico,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.IdAtencion ORDER BY d.Descripcion) AS NumDiagnosticos,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.IdPaciente, ORDER BY a.FechaIngreso) AS RN
    FROM Pacientes p
    JOIN Atenciones a ON p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
    JOIN AtencionesDiagnosticos ad ON a.IdAtencion = ad.IdAtencion
    JOIN Diagnosticos d ON ad.IdDiagnostico = d.IdDiagnostico
)
SELECT  T1.IdPaciente, 
    T1.IdAtencion,
    T1.Nombres, 
    T1.FechaIngreso,
    T2.FechaIngreso,
    T1.FechaEgreso,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 1 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 2 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico2,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 3 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico3,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 4 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico4,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 5 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico5,
    MAX( CASE WHEN T1.NumDiagnosticos = 6 THEN T1.Dignostico END) AS Dignostico6
    FROM PacientesDiagnosticos T1
    LEFT JOIN PacientesDiagnosticos T2
        ON T2.IdPaciente = T1.IdPaciente
        AND T2.RN = T1.RN - 1
    GROUP BY T1.IdPaciente,
           T1.IdAtencion,
           T1.Nombres,
           T1.FechaIngreso,
           T2.FechaIngreso,
           T1.FechaEgreso;
```

Comment: en el ROW_NUMBER() que pones, tengo que trabajar con el IdAtencion...ya que me sale error cuando uso el IdPaciente...un paciente tiene varias atenciones y cada atencion tiene una FechaIngreso :s...varias T2.FechaIngreso me salen vacio al momento de ejecutarla, cuando tienen que poner la fecha :s (si uso el IdAtencion tambien me salen vacios, nose que esta mal :s)

Comment: Cuando agregas `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.IdPaciente, ORDER BY a.FechaIngreso) AS RN` ¿Exactamente que error tienes?. En cuanto a si tienes que usar `IdAtencion`, no lo sé, no conozco la lógica de negocios, pero ¿entiendes la idea en general? hacer un numerador para cada `FechaIngreso` luego simplemente tenemos que agregar a la consulta la única fila dónde el numerador = numerador - 1. La primer fila siempre te traerá NULL.

Comment: Revisa visualmente la nueva columna `RN` para ver en primer lugar si efectivamente la genera de acuerdo a lo que necesitas

Comment: bueno estuve revisando la bd, he tenido que quitar el distinct volver hacer el codigo, he borrado unas cosas pero si, la idea tuya esta bien, ya el otro problema es aparte con los datos ingresados. Muchas gracias! Pero aun asi tengo que usar el IdAtencion! Gracias man!

Comment: Estupendo, me alegro!